# nmake makefile, linking objects files in a subfolder

Tags: makefile, nmake

My makefile defines a link command:

```
prod_link = $(LINK) $(LINK_FLAGS) -o$(PROD_OUT) $(PROD_OBJS)
```

where `$(PROD_OBJS)` is a list of object files of the form:

```
PROD_OBJS = objfile1.obj objfile2.obj objfile3.obj ... objfileN.obj
```

Now the makefile itself is at the root of my project directory.
It gets messy to have object and listing files at the root, I'd like to put them in a subfolder.

Building and outputing the obj files to a subfolder works, I'm doing it with suffixes and inference:

```
.s.obj:
    $(ASSEMBLY) $(FLAGS) $*.s -o Objects\$*.obj
```

The problem is to pass the `Objects` folder to the link command.

I tried:

```
prod_link = $(LINK) $(LINK_FLAGS) -o$(PROD_OUT) Objects\$(PROD_OBJS)
```

but only the first file in the list of object files gets the folder's name.

How can I pass the `Objects` subfolder to all files of my list `$(PROD_OBJS)`?

---

**EDIT**

I tried also

```
PROD_OBJS = $(patsubst %.ss,Object\%.obj, $(PROD_SRC))
```

but got:

```
makefile(51) : fatal error U1000: syntax error : ')' missing in macro invocation
Stop.
```

This is quite strange...

Comment: I'm not sure how similar NMAKE is to GnuMAKE, but you could try adding `Objects` to your VPATH? (`VPATH:=$(VPATH) Objects`). VPATH is a list of paths that the make utility will use to search for targets to rules. Also what is $(PROD_OUT) is it a single file?

Comment: `nmake` does not seem to like `:=`. `PROD_OUT` is the single final output file, yes.

Comment: Ok, maybe try "VPATH=Objects". How about also making a rule to generate $(PROD_OUT) a target e.g

`$(PROD_OUT):$(PROD_OBJS) (newline)(tab) $(LINK) $(LINK_FLAGS) -o$@ $<`

In this way, you can call $(PROD_OUT) as a target, and it will build your objects, provided that you have set VPATH correctly. What type of NMAKE is this.. Microsoft? I am not that familiar with NMAKE but I understand its syntax is very similar to gnu MAKE.

Comment: That error, is it because of the space before `$(PROD_SRC)`?

Comment: I don't know NMAKE either, but the core of the problem seems to be the use of patsubst. I'd suggest experimenting with patsubst in simple cases, verifying that it works, then using it construct PROD_OBJS. (And if this were GNUMake I'd rewrite the object rule: Object/%.obj: %.s ...)

Comment: `VPATH` still did not work. I have `$(PROD_OUT)` as a target already. The target calls to the `$(prod_link)` in my original post. It does that for historical reasons, I'll remove it. Microsoft nmake, yes!

Comment: I tested without the space before `$(PROD_OUT)`, no change.

Comment: @Beta: I tested the patsubst thing alright, it does not seem to work as I expect. But the strange thing is that `PROD_OBJS = $(PROD_SRC):.s=.obj)` does work fine!

Comment: @Gauthier, you have two `s`'s in your `patsubst` rule. Is that a typo in the question, or in your original makefile?

Comment: problem not fixed, no :(  . @BeeBand, my files do have the `.ss` extension. I wrote `.s` earlier, because it was a general question, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Maybe you should try using gnu make instead? The syntax is better documented :)

Comment: Yes, I am considering this as well. Only the fact that microsoft nmake is so old (1994) gives me the creeps.

Comment: @BeeBand: it looks like moving to GNU make was the thing to do. This seemed like a limitation of nmake. If you'd write that in an answer, I'd gladly select it as the valid answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nmake is *not* GNUMake, and is rather rubbish. See the [NMAKE Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd9y37ha%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) for details.

As far as your problem goes (translating `1.o 2.o 3.o` into `d/1.o d/2/o d/3.o`), try

```
OBJS= 1.o 2.o 3.o
# Looks wierd I know, but basically change ' ' to ' d/'
# (and it's not very robust!)
OBJS_WITH_PREFIX= d/$(OBJS: = d/)
!ERROR [$(OBJS_WITH_PREFIX)]
```

By the way, your pattern rule is lying to nmake. You say `.s.obj:`, which says "here is how to convert a .s file into a .obj," but then the commands you give actually create the object in a subfolder. You should have started the pattern rule with `.s{Objects\}.obj:`. See the docs for more details (*Search Paths in Rules*).

Comment: Thanks for the christmas eve answer. "is rather rubish", I agree. I switched to GNU make.

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party, but in case anyone else runs into the same problem:

This error

```
makefile(51) : fatal error U1000: syntax error : ')' missing in macro invocation
Stop.
```

is caused by the fact that the patsubst syntax doesn't seem to be supported by nmake. You can get around this by using the alternative syntax

```
$(var:suffix=replacement)
```

instead of

```
$(patsubst %suffix,%replacement,$(var))
```

(this is also valid in gnumake).